# session is not a super variable in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

Suppose I have in my rails app `lib/` folder some `module` declaration

```
module myModule
 class someClass

  def somemethod
   local_var = session(:some_hash)
  end
 end
end
```

the problem is that the `session` variables which is recognized in my `app/` folder is not recognized in my `lib/` folder. But I thought `session` was a super variable, that we could invoke everywhere, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and it's not a variable. It's a method accessible from inside your controllers and views.

Global variables in Ruby are prepended with `$`:

```
$example_global_variable
```

and, to be honest, you use them very rarely.

Comment: OK, I am coming from `php`, so I didn't know about this